# How to floor numbers to whole number in python

Tags: python, floor

I am wondering how can I floor `1,999,999` to `1,000,000` or `2,000,108` to `2,000,000` in python?
I used `math.floor()` but it's just for removing decimal part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
math.floor(num / 1000000) * 1000000
```

e.g.:

```
>>> num=1999999
>>> math.floor(num / 1000000) * 1000000
1000000.0
>>> num=2000108
>>> math.floor(num / 1000000) * 1000000
2000000.0
```

Comment: `num = 111; math.floor(num / 1000000) * 1000000` gives `0`, which is not at all what the OP expects (100).

Answer (score 0):

To round down positive integer to first digit

```
from math import floor

def r(n):
    gr = 10 ** (len(str(n))-1)
    return floor(n / gr) * gr

for i in [199_999, 200_100, 2_100, 315]:
    print(r(i))
```

Output

```
100000
200000
2000
300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def floor_integer(num):
    l = str(num)
    return int(l[0]) * pow(10, len(l) - 1)
```

I think that will fits your needs.

```
print(floor_integer(5))
# 5

print(floor_integer(133))
# 100

print(floor_integer(1543))
# 1000

print(floor_integer(488765))
# 400000

print(floor_integer(1999999))
# 1000000

print(floor_integer(2000108))
# 2000000
```